# Запуск reactjs на хостинге

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Делаю yarn build 
yarn global add serve
serve -s build

[image: Подгружаю файлы на хостинг и получаю ошибки]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import  firebase from 'firebase';
import {DB_CONFIG} from './Config.js'
import Collapsible from 'react-collapsible';

class App extends Component {

 constructor(){


    const login = window.localStorage.getItem('rr_login')
    if (login == '330') {
      console.log('пропусти')



      super()
      this.state = {
        currentItem: '',
        username: '',
        items: []
      }
      this.app = firebase.initializeApp(DB_CONFIG);
      const dateTime = new Date().getTime();
      const timestamp = Math.floor(dateTime / 1000);
      var key = parseInt(timestamp/86400);
      this.database = this.app.database().ref('driversApp/ordersData/').child(key);
    }
  }

  /* ... */
}

export default App;
```

Comment: а код `App.js` можно?

Comment: скорее всего в конструкторе забыли вызвать `super()`

Comment: добавили код dsit

Comment: Решили проблему

Answer (score 0):

Добавить в app.js либо проверить, чтоб попало под условие

super()

Comment: в вопросе то код зря убрали, может другим пользователям пригодится

Comment: `super` лучше всегда вызывать в самом начале, не добавлять в условия

Comment: import Show from './components/Show';
<Route  exact path='/show/' component={Show} />
<Link to={`/show/`}><button class="btn">Мои заказы</button></Link>

Есть еще такая проблема, не переходит на другие компоненты, хотя на локалке работает

Comment: лучше это в вопрос оформить

Comment: При переходе на вторую вкладку выдает ошибку

    "Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app)."

Comment: Мне ( как и другим ) сложно что-то сказать без кода)